# Wrong binding with array of string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am implementing some questionnaire. In my model for question I have PossibleAnswers, it is array of five string elements which user needs to input. But input has no effect, PossibleAnswers stays empty. What is wrong?

Here is my model for question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebUI.Entities;

namespace WebUI.Models
{
    public class QuestionVM
    {
        public QuestionVM() {}
        public QuestionVM(Question question)
        {
            ID = question.ID;
            Text = question.Text;
            IsAssociatedWithProfessor = question.IsAssociatedWithProfessor;
            IsAssociatedWithAssistant = question.IsAssociatedWithAssistant;
            int i = 0;
            foreach(PossibleAnswer possibleAnswer in question.PossibleAnswers)
            {
                if(i < 5)
                {
                    PossibleAnswers[i] = possibleAnswer.Text;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsAssociatedWithProfessor { get; set; }
        public bool IsAssociatedWithAssistant { get; set; }
        public string[] PossibleAnswers = new string[5];
        public Question ToQuestion(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            Question question = new Question
            {
                Text = this.Text,
                IsAssociatedWithProfessor = this.IsAssociatedWithProfessor,
                IsAssociatedWithAssistant = this.IsAssociatedWithAssistant,
                PossibleAnswers = new List<PossibleAnswer>()
            };
            //ID will null if creating new question
            if(ID != null)
            {
                question.ID = (int) ID;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PossibleAnswers[i]))
                {
                    PossibleAnswer existingPossibleAnswer = context.PossibleAnswers.SingleOrDefault(ans => ans.Text == this.PossibleAnswers[i]);
                    if (existingPossibleAnswer == null)
                    {
                        PossibleAnswer ans = new PossibleAnswer { Text = this.PossibleAnswers[i] };
                        context.PossibleAnswers.Add(ans);
                        question.PossibleAnswers.Add(ans);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        question.PossibleAnswers.Add(existingPossibleAnswer);
                    }
                }
            }
            return question;
        }
    }
}
```

Get and post methods for creating new question:

```
public ActionResult AddQuestion()
{
   return View(new QuestionVM());
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddQuestion(QuestionVM questionVM)
{
   try
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           Question question = questionVM.ToQuestion(context);
           context.Questions.Add(question);
           context.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Questions");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException exception)
    {
        //Log the error
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Trenutno nije moguće snimiti promjene, pokušajte ponovo.");
     }
     return View(questionVM);
}
```

And part of view for inputting possible answers of question:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group adding">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">@(i.ToString() + ".")</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PossibleAnswers[i - 1], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Odgovor" } })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PossibleAnswers[i - 1])
       </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `PossibleAnswers` is a public field. MVC binder does not bind fields, only properties. You should change your `PossibleAnswers` declaration to a property:

```
public string[] PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
```

You can initialize the array in your constructor:

```
public QuestionVM() 
{
    PossibleAnswers = new string[5];
}
```

Comment: After changing that I have error in browser: "Collection is read-only." Why?

Comment: I don't see, it just turned up in browser, doesn't say in which line :D

Comment: I can use list instead of array. But since it is empty when I send it to view, it will give index out of bound exception in this line:            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PossibleAnswers[i - 1], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Odgovor" } }) How to arrange that to work?

Comment: With your current view code you need to initialize the array in the constructor. I updated the answer

Comment: I know that and have done that previously, but still there is error.

Comment: Can you add breakpoints in your controller methods and see if the code is executed there or if it is an issue with model binding?

Comment: It gives an error when I submit form. I added breakpoint at first line in if statement of the post method, but it seems that it doesn't even get into if (ModelState.IsValid) {}. Here is the error log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7f14c97c91a2fde33028